# touchesBegan not being called sometimes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6.3

I have `touchesBegan` in my initial Login ViewController to dismiss the keyboard and cancel a custom AlertView. Though it works initially, `touchesBegan` is not being called after I logout with `performSegueWithIdentifier`.

```
//to resign keyboard
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        println("touchesBegan");
        self.view.endEditing(true)
       loginAlert.hideView()
       signupAlert.hideView()
}

//Logout
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("gotoLoginSegue", sender: self);
```

Comment: Is the problem that it doesn't work on returning to the view with the login statement or is it not working on a different view? The latter is obvious because of you don't listen for touches in each view controller it simply won't work

Comment: Its not working on the same view. I have the touchesBegan in Login View. It works initially. After login it moves to a different view. Then i logout using the logout statement from that view and return to the same login view. This time touchesBegan is not working.

Comment: Do you start listing on view did load AND dealloc it (do you do that in swft? I don't use it)? Also, add a log statement in the view did load just to make sure it actually fires. If it doesn't fire you've got an entirely different problem on your hands

Comment: viewDidLoad loads fine. I am not doing any dealloc in swift.

Comment: Do you have a gesture recognizer eating the touches?

Comment: That helped a lot, i had a UITapGestureRecognizer eating the touches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because i used both `UITapGestureRecognizer` and `touchesBegan`. I handled the scenario in `UITapGestureRecognizer` and removed the `touchesBegan` logic and it fix